# Parsing Kubernetes syslog logs with Logstash

Tags: logging, kubernetes, logstash, kubectl, logstash-grok

Kubernetes leaves logs in `/var/log/syslog`. Example:

```
I1021 12:57:47.052671   35084 setters.go:73] Using node IP: "10.11.22.33."
```

I understand that the `I` stands for `info`, followed by a certain code, then a timestamp. But what is the code after that? What does `setters.go` mean? I also see that the actual log message comes after `]`.

I would like to parse these with Logstash, but I couldn't find any documentation about what each field in the header supposed to mean.

I could write these parsers myself with the `grok` filter, of course, but first I would like to understand what does each message mean.

Answer (score 0):

> I1021 12:57:47.052671   35084 setters.go:73] Using node IP: "10.11.22.33."
>
> **/var/log/syslog** or **/var/log/messages**: general messages, as well as system-related information. Essentially, this log stores all activity data across the global system. Note that activity for Redhat-based systems, such as CentOS or Rhel, are stored in messages, while Ubuntu and other Debian-based systems are stored in Syslog.

This is kubelet entry:

[`setters.go`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/kubelet/nodestatus/setters.go) - is script written in GO that updates the daemon endpoints on the node.

[`73`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/kubelet/nodestatus/setters.go#L73) - is number of line which prints the message

> `klog.V(2).Infof("Using node IP: %q", nodeIP.String())`

If you are using `systemd` you should be using `jurnalctl -u kubelet`

You should also check Kubernetes documentation for [Looking at logs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-cluster/#looking-at-logs).

> For now, digging deeper into the cluster requires logging into the relevant machines. Here are the locations of the relevant log files. (note that on systemd-based systems, you may need to use  `journalctl`  instead)
>
> #### Master
>
> - `/var/log/kube-apiserver.log`  - API Server, responsible for serving the API
> - `/var/log/kube-scheduler.log`  - Scheduler, responsible for making scheduling decisions
> - `/var/log/kube-controller-manager.log`  - Controller that manages replication controllers
>
> #### Worker Nodes
>
> - `/var/log/kubelet.log`  - Kubelet, responsible for running containers on the node
> - `/var/log/kube-proxy.log`  - Kube Proxy, responsible for service load balancing

If you are looking for Application logs then please check [Troubleshoot Applications](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-application/).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Crou provided `35084` refers to the PID of the process which wrote the log. However looking at the klog code for this it would [appear](https://github.com/kubernetes/klog/blob/6632ba5cc9a5331c853a2c6dbc0fbb125e6e7b94/internal/buffer/buffer.go#L140) at some point this could be changed to be the thread id instead.

Comment: You will be able to comment when you will have reached the suitable reputation. The answers should be used to answer the question and not as comments.